# How to know if my camel route is up and running to process a message from queue

Tags: routes, apache-camel, queue, ibm-mq, message-queue

I have a camel route which retrieves messages ( in xml format) from an IBM MQ and writes its equivalent entity object into database. Now, i have a requirement to check if my camel route is up and running to retrieve messages from the IBM MQ at any point of time.

I have an UI app which needs to know at regular interval( lets say every 60 seconds) if camel route is able retrieve messages from Queue fine or not. My UI app should get a success REST response if my route is up and running to retrieve messages fine at that point of time. My UI app can trigger a dummy payload to IBM MQ. That is possible. Is there any way to acheive this requirement?

Comment: Exactly what you you want to know?  If you are able to send some a "are you alive" message to your camel route and have it respond to such message, this would test end to end that the "request" message is getting to the queue, being picked up by the route, and the response is making it back to your UI app.

Comment: If you are just interested if client is connected to MQ via a SVRCONN channel you could inquire the channel status, or inquire the queue to check for IPPROCS to see if a reader is attached, this is methods noted by Daniels answer.  Keep in mind just because MQ things the SVRCONN channel is RUNNING or that there is a IPPROC on the queue it does not mean the client app that is connected to that queue and has the queue open is still active, for instance if the SVRCONN channel has the HBINT set to the default 300, if your app goes down the QM would not know for up to 360 seconds (6 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example the [Inquire Channel Status](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087540_.htm) or [Inquire Queue Status](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087880_.htm) Programmable Command Format (PCF) messages. There are a lot of other [PCF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086870_.htm) messages available to programmatically monitor IBM MQ. Have a look at the [PCFMessageAgent](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/pcf/PCFMessageAgent.html) class to get an idea of how to use PCF messages in Java.